# Unarchiving .tar files and gunzipping all .gz files for all subdirectories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, tar, gunzip

I have many .tar files which I am unarchiving from an HDD to a server using tar xvf, then I manually go through the directories from the unarchived .tar file and use gunzip *.gz to unzip the .gz files. Is there a way to do all of this with one command using terminal?

Comment: Please show what did you try. Also, this may be a question better suited to https://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks Nebril, superuser does seem better suited.